# Is a sample of 1961 people out of a population of 225,000,000 a sample size that is too small? If so, why?

Tags: proportion, sample, population

I am working by a set of problems on a single question in my textbook. The question explained that there was a recent survey of 1961 adults out of a population of 225,000,000 and asked me to construct a 95% confidence interval estimate of the percentage of all adults on the "Do not call registry". I completed this problem quite easily using the methods prescribed previously in the text.

The following problem asked me if the sample size of 1961 was unreasonably small for the population size, which I do not know how to determine. I am starting to think that the question simply wants me to use my own opinionated reasoning.

Comment: Hi Nicholas, welcome to CV. Textbook questions are welcome here but are treated differently. Please add the `self-study` tag (via an edit of your question) and read through its [tag wiki info](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) which explains how it works (for both people who ask and people who answer).

Comment: I think you can bring more than opinion to bear on this question. In particular, you can talk about what the interval actually means (this is a somewhat subtle issue that's worth the time to understand), and the importance of having a representative sample (as well as how that might be achieved, given the assumptions under which your interval was derived). There's some scope for opinion, but one that relies on understanding the statistical issues.

Comment: Can you at least give me a hint on how I would begin to do this? As of right now I am totally stumped, although I have estimated the sample size to be about .001% of the population.

Comment: I gave two large ones in my previous comment - what does a confidence interval *mean* -- i.e. what probability statement is associated with that 95% (or whatever) interval? and how does your interval rely on a representative sample (does your interval not rely on random sampling? *Why*?). If you have that assumed random sampling, and given the appropriate probability statement, what does a CI indicate at *whatever* sample size you have? When you have considered those issues, the answer - or at least what things it might depend on - should hopefully be clear.

Comment: The main point of this question is to help you understand that whether a random sample comprises 0.001% or 10% of the population has essentially no relevance to the accuracy of estimates made with it.